# Azure Data Factory File encryption using Public Key

Tags: azure-data-factory, public-key-encryption

I have a situation where I have been supplied with a public key. I can encrypt a file using command line gpg/pgp. However I want to use ADF to save the file to a blob store in it's encrypted form using the customer-managed public key. I cannot do it by importing the private key pair into a key vault and using that key vault to encrypt the storage container - as I don't have the private key pair (it is not visible within the system which receives the encrypted file).

Is there a way to do this in ADF? I have seen one or two articles which use python scripts to decrypt a file in ADF, but not one to encrypt a file. Thanks for any help.

Comment: A customer-managed key can only be configured on an empty data Factory. The data factory can't contain any resources such as linked services, pipelines and data flows. It is recommended to enable customer-managed key right after factory creation. please check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/enable-customer-managed-key) and let me know if it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`Encrypt Azure Data Factory with customer-managed keys` feature is to encrypt the data factory environment i.e., to encrypt data that datafactory storing in the system. Unfortunately there is no out of box feature in Azure Data factory to perform encryption/decryption of files.

Though you can encrypt the data in Storage account and also in ADF separately using customer-managed public key.

I have repro the same and it is working fine for me.

Go the storage account and click on Encryption on the left side of the panel.

[image]

Select the key vault and the key which you want to encrypt the data.

[image]

In ADF also, go to the `Manager` option on the left panel and click on `Customer managed key` and add Key URL to encrypt the ADF environment and data associated with it.

[image]

**Note:** A customer-managed key can only be configured on an empty data Factory. The data factory can't contain any resources such as linked services, pipelines and data flows. It is recommended to enable customer-managed key right after factory creation.

Comment: This solution works ok only if you have the private key (the private key also contains the public key). In other tasks/processes, I have access to the Private key and created a key vault, and linked it to a storage account to encrypt the data.

But with this particular recipient CRM application, I only have the Public key which enables me to encrypt files and send them on to the recipient. The Private key is internal to the recipient CRM system and not visible. I have tried to load the Public key into an Azure Key Vault as a pem/pfx file, but Key Vault will only accept a Private Key.

Comment: So I believe the only solution will be use some sort of python or other script within an ADF pipeline to enable a file to be encrypted.

I have seen this solution https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/pgp-file-decrypt-using-azure-data-factory-richard-kashyap-deka. But this article shows how to decrypt a file in ADF. What I am looking for is how to encrypt a file with only the Public key.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK that's the only solution because ADF doesn't support encryption of data in storage account.